# Как сделать правильное название города в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, строки

Здраствуйте! Я начинающий программист и пока делал новый проект столкнулся с такой задачей.
Когда моему голосовому помощнику говоришь

> Какая погода в Казани?

Он посылает на сайт с прогнозом погоды строку

> Казани

Но сайт принимает название города. То есть "Казань". Я бы мог просто заменить в коде последнею букву на 'ь', но тогда если скажешь

> Какая погода в Ижевске?

Станет ещё хуже. То есть он отправит строку "Ижевскь". Скажите пожалуйста, какую программу нужно написать на Python что бы преобразовывать "Казани" в "Казань", Ижевске в Ижевск, Москве в Москва и т.д.

Comment: Ижевскь ничем не хуже Ижевска, а вот Москвь...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте в свой алгоритм добавить прослойку с использованием библиотеки pymorphy2 (необходима установка):

```
pip install pymorphy2
```

Согласно [документации](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#:%7E:text=%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2,%D0%B8%20%D1%82.%D0%B4.) анализатор позволяет ставить слово в нужную форму. Например, ставить слово во множественное число, менять падеж слова и т.д.

При работе используется словарь OpenCorpora; для незнакомых слов строятся гипотезы. Библиотека достаточно быстрая.

Подробнее о падежах [здесь](https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/grammemes.html#:%7E:text=POS%0A%27INFN%27-,%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6,-%D0%93%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0).

Comment: По этой ссылке: https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/guide.html#inflection
Вы получите ещё больше необходимой информации.